# How to forward a text with special characters in REST responses, in Delphi?

Tags: rest, delphi, special-characters, delphi-xe7

Please help. I'm trying to learn REST concepts and make the first programs using Delphi and REST objects. I came across a problem that I don’t know how to solve. In the database I have a test with special characters from my mother tongue (Bosnian): č, ć, đ, š, ž. When I pass this text via the GET method, objects that parse and display this text in objects on the form display these characters as "?", "æ", "æè" etc.
I researched and tried unsuccessfully to solve the problem. I tried to use the Utf8ToAnsi function and put iso-8859-2 instead of UTF-8 in the RESTClient, RESTRequest and RESTResponce object parameters.
Please for help, instruction or advice on how to solve or investigate this problem.

Source code on server side:

```
procedure TWebModule1.UsersGet(Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse);
var
  a: TJSONArray;
  o: TJSONObject;
  i: Integer;
  Q1: TADOQuery;
begin
  Q1:=TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  Q1.Connection:= BasicDBConn.Konekcija;
  with Q1 do
  begin
    Active:=False;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('Select USER_ID, USER_NAME, ROLE_NAME  from USERS, ROLES  ' +
      ' where USERS.ROLE_ID=ROLES.ROLE_ID ');
    Active:= True;
  end;
  a := TJSONArray.Create;

  if Q1.RecordCount > 0 then
  begin
    for i:=1 to Q1.RecordCount do
    begin
      o := TJSONObject.Create;
      o.AddPair('USER_ID', Q1.Fields.Fields[0].Value);
      o.AddPair('USER_NAME', Q1.Fields.Fields[1].Value);
      o.AddPair('ROLE_NAME', Q1.Fields.Fields[2].Value);
      Q1.Next;
      a.AddElement(o);
    end;
  end;

  Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
  Response.Content := a.ToString;
  a.DisposeOf;
  Q1.Free;
end;
```

on client side:

```
procedure TGlavna.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RESTRequest.Resource := 'Users';
  RESTRequest.Method   := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGet;
  RESTRequest.Response := RESTResponse;

  RESTRequest.Execute;

  if assigned(fJSONArray) then fJSONArray.DisposeOf;
  fJSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(RESTResponse.Content) as TJSONArray;

  if RESTResponse.Content.IsEmpty then Application.MessageBox('Empty', 'Information', MB_OK)
    else Memo1.Lines.Add(RESTResponse.Content);
end;
```

This is what a data in DB looks like

USER_ID     USER_NAME       ROLE_ID
u1          Test User       2
u2          T_č_ć_š_đ_ž     1
u3          t_Č_Ć_Ž_Đ_Š     1
u4          Bradić Kenan    1

In web browser, responce data is:

[{"USER_ID":"u1","USER_NAME":"Test User","ROLE_ID":"2"},{"USER_ID":"u3","USER_NAME":"t_È_Æ_Ž_Ð_Š","ROLE_ID":"1"},{"USER_ID":"u4","USER_NAME":"Bradiæ Kenan","ROLE_ID":"1"},{"USER_ID":"u2","USER_NAME":"T_è_æ_š_ð_ž","ROLE_ID":"1"}]

```
Headers in web browser:
General:
    Request URL: http://localhost:8080/Users
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Remote Address: [::1]:8080
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers:
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 228
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
    Date: Mon, 27 Dec 2021 17:07:54 GMT
Request Headers:
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: localhost:8080
    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
```

Thank you...

Comment: Officially JSON only supports UTF8 encoding. So trying to work around it is bound to fail. Of course, when it comes to encoding it is also important not only what how your client encodes and decodes data, but also what encoding server uses. Another question is what is encoding used in a database.

Comment: Dalija, thank you very much for your comment.

I did not specifically set the charset for DB, I use simple MS Access DB and I assume that the one from OS was used (iso-8859-2 is for Bosnia). It is interesting that when I do the POST method to save data tu DB from the client form using the same REST objects (with the same parameters for charsets), words with these special characters are entered correctly in this DB. I see this when I open the database directly in MS Access. So "only" when I do GET I have problem :-(

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Embarcadero Delphi XE7

Comment: This is rather old one. I added it as a tag because there are differences between versions so it is prudent to add that information. I don't have too much experience with ANSI encodings as I am always using UTF-8 so I cannot tell you what settings you need to apply ( or if that is even possible).

Comment: Dalija, I am really grateful for the advice and time you took for this conversation!

Comment: Can you include an example of the full HTTP GET response - including headers - in your question? (you may use the developer mode in a web browser)

Comment: Mjn, thanks for comment! I added that in my question

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar  Hello Dalija. Updating status ... The problem with forwarding data with special characters was solved by setting ResponseType parameters, but there was another problem - forwarding text with special characters in the request parameters. It did not work from the client application. But it worked on a web browser, so the server side was OK. I found couple more threads on this site with a similar problem. I tried my test client and server applications on Delphi Tokyo and everything works. You were right! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP response contains this line:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

So the client handles interprets the Response content as ISO-85591 encoded instead of UTF-8.
Your server side codes contains this line:

```
Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
```

Your server side code should clear the charset=ISO-85591 part.

Comment: Mjn, thank you very much!!! 
My default charset in Windows is ISO-8859-1. Now everything works after I overloaded it with:
 Response.ContentType := 'application/json; Charset=utf-8';
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your value with base64, and create a JSON payload to translate the JSON payload with REST API.

Moreover, if the value is sensitive, you can encrypt it with AES, and then translate it with REST API.

What technology will you use in server side? PHP? or .NET or JAVA? All 3 technologies used AES in native code, but there are little differences between the technologies.

If you used PHP or PHP + Laravel, you might reference my sample project in [my GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Dennies-Chang/delphi-aes-256-cbc-laravel-sample), the description you can read from my [article](https://firemonkeylessons.blogspot.com/2022/07/encrypt-in-delphi-decrypt-in-laravel.html).